# WordPress Nav Menu Items Broken on localhost

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, wp-nav-menu-item

I'm having major issues with my `local development` version of a client's site.

I've been working on their blog section and began getting `404 errors` when using the pagination links for categories, or posts by author.

After doing some research the most common solution seemed to be to go to WP Admin Area and reset the permalink settings. So I did that, and that is where the fun really began.

Now, none of the nav menu items work at all. If I click any of them I get a 404 error - although they don't render the 404.php file, just a generic page with "**NOT FOUND** The requested `URL /Clients/blah-blah-blah/index.php` was not found on this server."

Looking further into it the most recommended course of action is to amend the `.htaccess` file, which I have, but to no avail.

At present, the `.htacess` file has:

```
**ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Clients/Bubs%20World%20Dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Clients/Bubs%20World%20Dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress**
```

I've tried other solutions along the same lines but they don't seem to work.

If anyone has any ideas on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Don